# factoring of polynomial of degree $x^3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

$$x^3+6 x^2+11x +6 = (x+1)(x+2)(x+3)$$

Looking for a very detailed description of how to factor this, and just factoring in general.

Additionally, what type of problem is this, so I can make better and more relevant searches for help on future questions. Is it a cubic trinomial?

Comment: You know the Rational Root Theorem?

Comment: I'm reading about it right now http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way, but unfortunatelly only works some times is the following:

Step 1: Guess a root $a$ of $P(x)$.
Step 2: Divide by $x-a$.
Step 3: Factor the remaining quadratic.

The following usually helps:

Let $P(x)=a_3x^3+a_2x^2+a_1x+a_0$. If all coefficients are integers, and $r=\frac{p}{q}$ is a irreducible rational root, then $p|a_0$ and $q|a_3$.

So for your problem, the only possible rational roots are $\pm 1, \pm 2, \pm 3$ and $\pm 6$, either one works or you need to rely on the cubic formula (which you can find easely but it is hard to memorize)...

Comment: ehm , how to rely on the cubic formula ?? Thanks in advance

Comment: I think I got the idea

Comment: Any factoring you find in "precalculus" will not involve the cubic formula.